# How to programmatically read azure web job log

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I have a continuous web job that is triggered by a queue. The `Functions` method accepts a `TextWriter` parameter, and I use that to write the output of my job.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("build")] ProjectTrigger projectInfo, TextWriter log)
```

I can browse the `azure-jobs-host-archive` storage container in the Azure portal and view the latest file to see the host log, containing JSON that includes the following path to the actual log in the `azure-webjobs-hosts` container.

```
 // ...
 "Arguments": {
    "projectInfo": "{\"ProjectId\":1}",
    "log": null
  },
  "Reason": "AutomaticTrigger",
  "StartTime": "2015-03-31T00:22:33.0447775+00:00",
  "OutputBlob": {
    "ContainerName": "azure-webjobs-hosts",
    "BlobName": "output-logs/06001f0c69064d4289b3501d0064f11c.txt"
  },
 // ...
```

With that, I can browse to the `azure-webjobs-hosts` container in the Azure portal and find the file specified by `BlobName`.

That's great, but how can I do this programmatically? I want to be able to display the output log in my web application. If I knew the path of host archive file while the job is running, I could store it in SQL and access it later. Is this possible?

Comment: This might be something, but I haven't found any documentation on how to use it. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the exact answer I was looking for, but you can save the job log to a specific blob path using `BlobAttribute`, where `ProjectId` and `Id` are properties of `ProjectTrigger`.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("build")] ProjectTrigger projectInfo, 
                   [Blob("projecthistory/{ProjectId}/{Id}.txt", FileAccess.Write)] TextWriter log)
```